# Looking for a library/class to create a password protected archive

Tags: c#, compression

The features I want: 
1. compress files and folders into archive.
2. password protect it
3. have an option to exclude subdirectories from being included in the archive.

I tried:

dotnetzip : 
has everything except a straightforward way to exclude folders. It does have a way to exclude folders, but I am unable to solve the problems I am getting with it (spend half a day at it). want something more simple.

sharpziplib: 
no docs , couldn't figure out how to use it .

Basically I want to tell the library to function like this:

```
zip.AddDIr("c:\opera") 
zip.excludeDir("C:\opera\1\cache")
```

Is there such a lib ? or anything else I can do ?

Thanks

Comment: I suggest, you post your problems with dotnetzip, so we can solve those.

Comment: Agrees with Daniel's comment - post your problems with DotNetZip so we can help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use System.IO.Compression; you can choose which files to compress; whether create a single compressd file; and whether encrypt the contents;

If you encrypt first, compression will hardly reduce any size.

```
public static void Compress(FileInfo fi)
        {
            // Get the stream of the source file.
            using (FileStream inFile = fi.OpenRead())
            {
                // Prevent compressing hidden and already compressed files.
                if ((File.GetAttributes(fi.FullName) & FileAttributes.Hidden)
                    != FileAttributes.Hidden & fi.Extension != ".cmp")
                {
                    // Create the compressed file.
                    using (FileStream outFile =
                            File.Create(fi.FullName + ".cmp"))
                    {
                        using (DeflateStream Compress =
                            new DeflateStream(outFile,
                            CompressionMode.Compress))
                        {
                            // Copy the source file into 
                            // the compression stream.
                            byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
                            int numRead;
                            while ((numRead = inFile.Read(buffer,
                                    0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
                            {
                                Compress.Write(buffer, 0, numRead);
                            }
                            Console.WriteLine("Compressed {0} from {1} to {2} bytes.",
                            fi.Name, fi.Length.ToString(), outFile.Length.ToString());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

You can also look at tradional ZIP file format compression:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/ZipStorer.aspx

You can use the following methods in ZipStorer class by directly including it in your project:

```
private static void CompressFile(string srcFileName, string zipFileName) 
private static void DecompressFile(string zipFileName, string unzipFolder)
```

Comment: The problem is, that DeflateStream doesn't create a valid Zip file. It seems to be missing some file headers. Windows for example can't interpret it.

Comment: yes it uses the LZ77 algorithm and Huffman coding.